# JPA / Hibernate @OneToMany with optional Child on JoinTable - Save parent affect multiple Inserts on JoinTable

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, join

I have a relation between Parent (Property) and Children (Credit), my Hibernate Configuration works fine for me as long I don`t try to save a new Child (Credit) by Cascade through the Parent (Property).

**Hibernate Configurations:**

```
@Entity
public class Property implements Ownable {

    ...

        @Valid 
        // ALSO TRIED WITH CascadeType.ALL !!!
        @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinTable(
                name = "PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="PROPERTY_ID", nullable = false), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CREDIT_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
        )
        List<NotActiveCredit> creditOptions = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

}

@Entity
public class NotActiveCredit extends Credit {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name                = "PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS",
        inverseJoinColumns  = @JoinColumn(name="PROPERTY_ID", nullable = false), 
        joinColumns         = @JoinColumn(name = "CREDIT_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    )
    @NotNull @NonNull 
    Property    property;
}
```

**Controller Call:**

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String save (
        @ModelAttribute("property") @Valid Property formProperty, 
        BindingResult errors, 
        ModelMap modelMap
) {
    if (!errors.hasErrors()) {

        // formProperty has new Credit in the creditOptions List
        // SAVE ONLY DELEGATS TO SPRING DATA REPOSITORY ...
        final Property savedProperty = propertyService.save(formProperty);
        ...     

    } else {
        // BLABLA
    }
}
```

The Logging looks like:

```
Enter InvestmentController.save( ... )
Enter PropertyServiceImpl.save( ... ) 

insert into not_active_credit (id, interest_rate_nominal_in_percent, name_of_institution, redemption_at_begin_in_percent, special_redemption_each_year_in_percent) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [NUMERIC] - [null]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [test]
binding parameter [3] as [NUMERIC] - [null]
binding parameter [4] as [NUMERIC] - [null]

insert into property_credit_options (property_id, credit_id) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]

Exit PropertyServiceImpl.save Returns Property

// THEN WHEN IT CLOSE THE TRANSACTION IT WANTS TO INSERT JOIN TABLE AGAIN!
insert into property_credit_options (property_id, credit_id) values (?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]

SQL Error: -104, SQLState: 23505
integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10222 table: PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS
```

My Object`s Content
[image]
Any hints are very welcome.

**Edit:**
Additional Information. After Call of Repository.Save the List is still considered as dirty (dirty=true). Shouldn't it be false then when it has been just saved, because in console I can see it just send SQL to db making an insert. While debugging if I give the List the dirty=false then the second time Insert will not be triggered more and everything is fine. Why doesn`t it set it to false after sending inserts to DB. It shouldn't be dirty more, or do I think wrong?

**SOLUTION**

As crizzis suggested I removed `@JoinTable` from collection property `creditOptions` in class `Property` and added `mappedBy='property'`. The Collection is now updateable from parent.

```
@Valid 
@OneToMany(mappedBy="property", fetch = LAZY, cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
Collection<NotActiveCredit>     creditOptions = new ArrayList<>();
```

On the other side on class `NotActiveCredit` it is as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(
        name                = "PROPERTY_CREDIT_OPTIONS",
        inverseJoinColumns  = @JoinColumn(name="PROPERTY_ID", nullable = false), 
        joinColumns         = @JoinColumn(name = "CREDIT_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
)
@NotNull  
Property    property;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the association entry is being inserted twice into the join table is that you've actually declared *two separate* associations (which just happen to be using the same join table) intead of just one.

When modelling a bidirectional association in JPA, one of the side must be *the owning side*, and the other side must be the *inverse side*. The inverse side is the one whose association mapping declares the `mappedBy` attribute.

The solution is, simply, to declare one of the sides of the association as the inverse side, and remove the `@JoinTable` annotation from that side. Otherwise JPA will treat each side as a separate unidirectional association.

Note that for all JPA knows, you could for some reason want to have two separate unidirectional associations (using different join tables, for example). JPA simply does not automagically know your intentions - you need the `mappedBy` attribute to make them clear.

Comment: Hey there, awesome, I just removed JoinTable from `NotActiveCredit` class and it already works. `mappedBy` was not necassary.

Comment: This will still be treated as a separate mapping. The only difference is that `@ManyToOne` uses a join column by default, so you will probably see an extra `PROPERTY_ID` column in the `NONACTIVECREDIT` table. What is more, `Property.creditOptions` and `NotActiveCredit.property` will **not** be kept in sync by JPA

Comment: The Table `not_active_credit` created only one `property_id`, but I will have a closer look with the sync. Btw. the @ManyToOne annotation has no `mappedBy`, where would you suggest to add it? Thank you.

Comment: Well, a single `property_id` is already redundant, since all the information regarding the association between `Property` and `NotActiveCredit` was supposed to be stored in the join table. As for `mappedBy`, you should add it to `@OneToMany`, and move the `@JoinTable` annotation to `NotActiveCredit`. This way, `NotActiveCredit` will become the owning side

Comment: Hey Crizzis, you are absolutly right. There were of cause the redundant `property_id` on the `not_active_credit` table. I did as you suggested, and first it still works and second, the redundant `property_id` is gone. Good catch, are you Hibernate Developer? :-)

Comment: Btw I updated the "solution" in my question, hope now everything fine :-) Thank you again.